# React component DRY refactoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to refactor code to make it a bit cleaner

this element

```
const {type} = this.state
...
<div>
  <label>Some label:
    <select
      name="type"
      onChange={this.onSelect}
      className="form-control form-select mb-2">
      {type.map(item => (
        <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

working with that piece of state:

```
...
,
type: [
  { name: 'Choose...', value: null },
  { name: 'Type#1', value: 'white' },
  { name: 'Type#2', value: 'black' }
],
...
```

because of many of the same `select`ors I'd like to have separate component like so:

```
const SelectInputGroup = ({
  label,
  name,
  onChange
}) => {
  return (
    <div><label>{label}
    <select
      name={name}
      onChange={onChange}
      className="form-control form-select mb-2 mr-3">
      {name.map(item => (  <<<-- error here
        <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>
      ))}
     </select>
     </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and pass properties to it

```
<SelectInputGroup
  label="Some Label"
  name="type"
  onChange={this.OnSelect}
/>
```

and got error "name.map is not a function" on <<< line

tried `{this.state.name.map(item => (` - error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

tried `{{name}.map(item => (` - error "{(intermediate value)}.map is not a function"

I feel there is a bad thing inside )) , but can't figure out where it is ))

Comment: `name` = `type` ( a string, not an array ). This is what you pass to `SelectInputGroup`. You probably want to pass `name={this.state.type}` instead.

Comment: `type`  is `const {type} = this.state` - its an array

Comment: `name="type"` is a string, `name={type}` is an array then.

Comment: You are passing `name` as a string to your `SelectInputGroup` as @Federkun pointed out. Then you are destructuring it from your props. So it is not an array in your component right now.

Comment: Big thanks 2 all, its working now.

Comment: Ask such question on codereview.stack